# Chrome Driver - Still timing out after 60 seconds even with --no-options

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an automated task that runs for a long time. Sometimes, it takes over a minute for the webpage to fully load so I have tried to set the default timeout in two different ways. Both do not work, I still get that default timeout after 60 seconds error.

```
public IWebDriver driver;

public DataAuditsUtility()
{
       driver = new ChromeDriver();
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);

}
```

I have also tried like this...

```
public IWebDriver driver;
public ChromeOptions options;

public DataAuditsUtility()
{
       options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

}
```

From what I have seen, both of these should work.. I am starting to think it may be an issue with how I am instantiating the chrome driver. What I do, is I have a class DataAuditsUtility, that has its own instance of WebDriver and I instantiate it and set it up in the constructor. This class has a bunch of methods that make actions on the page.

In the test class, I instantiate this class and just call its methods. The automation runs great however the only issue is I can not figure out how to increase the URL timeout. Any ideas as to why the above does not work? Thanks!

Also worth nothing in this solution that I do not have a config file anywhere. We actually do not use selenium in the solution other than this one test class so I would like to contain all configurations in here rather than a config file elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4874) reported where webdriver timed-out at a maximum of 60 seconds.

here is a quote from that:

> Each driver class has a constructor overload that allows you to set
> the timeout for each command. Here is an example for the FirefoxDriver
> to set the command timeout to 5 minutes:
>
> IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), null,
> TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
>
> You can find similar constructor overloads for InternetExplorerDriver,
> ChromeDriver, and RemoteWebDriver.

and

> When using these constructors it appears that the WebDriverWait is
> overridden.
>
> IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(), null,
> TimeSpan.FromHours(2));
>
> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,
> TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)); ...
>
> This caused it to wait for 2 hours rather than two minutes.

So it appears you can set a value on instantiation.

Comment: So are you suggesting I use the firefox driver or switch to the WebDriverWait approach?

Comment: As stated,  you can constructor overload any Webdriver, Firefox is just an example.

Comment: Isnt that what I am doing in the original post? I do not see how this is any different, my problem is that it does not seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: Do you see a difference in  the driver = ?  There is a key difference

Comment: The only difference I see is using a FirefoxDriver with a FireboxBinary()? I guess I can try switching to that to see if it helps. The driver does not matter too much, chrome just seems to be the most stable.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying.. of course. Looking into the ChromeDriver class I see additional overloads. Ugh, why did I not do this in the first place.. Will try with ChromeDriver and report back here. Thanks!